# How to load a csv file into tksheet

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How do you save and load csv files into the Python tkinter table widget `tksheet` found here https://github.com/ragardner/tksheet using a standard tkinter window

Answer (score 0):

This very basic example adds new commands to the built in popup menu of tksheet using
`self.sheet.popup_menu_add_command()`. It uses Pythons `csv` module combined with `tkinter`s `filedialog`, `os.path.normpath` and `io` to read and write csv files

More information can be found here:

- https://github.com/ragardner/tksheet/wiki
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html?highlight=tkinter#module-tkinter
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=io#text-i-o
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html?highlight=os%20normpath#os.path.normpath

```py
from tksheet import Sheet
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import csv
from os.path import normpath
import io


class demo(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.withdraw()
        self.title("tksheet")
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.sheet = Sheet(self.frame,
                           data = [[f"Row {r}, Column {c}" for c in range(6)] for r in range(21)])
        self.sheet.enable_bindings("all", "edit_header", "edit_index")
        self.frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nswe")
        self.sheet.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nswe")
        self.sheet.popup_menu_add_command("Open csv", self.open_csv)
        self.sheet.popup_menu_add_command("Save sheet", self.save_sheet)
        self.sheet.set_all_cell_sizes_to_text()
        self.sheet.change_theme("light green")
        
        # center the window and unhide
        self.update_idletasks()
        w = self.winfo_screenwidth() - 20
        h = self.winfo_screenheight() - 70
        size = (900, 500)
        x = (w/2 - size[0]/2)
        y = h/2 - size[1]/2
        self.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (size + ((w/2 - size[0]/2), h/2 - size[1]/2)))
        self.deiconify()

    def save_sheet(self):
        filepath = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(parent = self,
                                                title = "Save sheet as",
                                                filetypes = [('CSV File','.csv'),
                                                             ('TSV File','.tsv')],
                                                defaultextension = ".csv",
                                                confirmoverwrite = True)
        if not filepath or not filepath.lower().endswith((".csv", ".tsv")):
            return
        try:
            with open(normpath(filepath), "w", newline = "", encoding = "utf-8") as fh:
                writer = csv.writer(fh,
                                    dialect = csv.excel if filepath.lower().endswith(".csv") else csv.excel_tab,
                                    lineterminator = "\n")
                writer.writerows(self.sheet.yield_sheet_rows(get_header = False, get_index = False))
        except:
            return
                
    def open_csv(self):
        filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent = self, title = "Select a csv file")
        if not filepath or not filepath.lower().endswith((".csv", ".tsv")):
            return
        try:
            with open(normpath(filepath), "r") as filehandle:
                filedata = filehandle.read()
            self.sheet.set_sheet_data([r for r in csv.reader(io.StringIO(filedata),
                                                             dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(filedata),
                                                             skipinitialspace = False)])
        except:
            return


app = demo()
app.mainloop()
```